# OpenIddict- How To Enable Client To Request Data About All The Users Who Grant It Permissions

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openiddict

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to enable a 3 party client app to request data about all the users that grant it access to their account.
For example: if a 3 party client request access for user posts, is it possible to enable it to request all the posts for all the users that grant them access in one request?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting scenario, and not exactly something you can trivially solve in pure OAuth 2.0 implementations, since an access token usually represents a single user, not multiple ones.

One way to solve that would be to use `OpenIddictAuthorizationManager` and its `FindByApplicationIdAsync` methods to list all the authorizations bound to a specific client, and the "subjects" (i.e the user identifiers) associated to the authorizations.